# Connection Refused on Concurrent connection to openerp with xmlrpc (via python)

Tags: python, multithreading, odoo, python-multithreading, stress-testing

I've tried to build a stress test sistem which provide multiple concurent user login. The scheme is 1 thread for 1 user login. But i cant login with multiple user at the same time (concurent).

At the other side, i've tried to login with multiple user in sequential scheme (with thread.lock and thread.release over login method), and it works.

Can i login with multiple user at the same time on python thread scheme like this?

This is my code
(**Updated:**
i've update my code, and now i tried to read via xml_rpc with multithread.
Open Connection/Login is OK, but the i always get the **Failed Return on Reading Method**..
):

This threading class:

```
class theUser (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, row, dbhost, xml_port, dbuser, dbpassword, dbname):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID   = threadID
        self.name       = str(row[0])
        self.pswd       = str(row[1])
        self.msg        = ''
        self.xml_port   = xml_port
        self.params={'dbhost'   : dbhost,
                    'dbuser'    : dbuser,
                    'dbpassword': dbpassword,
                    'dbname'    : dbname,
                    'user'      : str(row[0]),
                    'password'  : str(row[1])
                }

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.sock_common    = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://%s:%s/xmlrpc/common' % (dbhost, xml_port))
            self.uid = self.sock_common.login(self.params['dbname'], self.name, self.pswd)                    

            self._read_data()

        except:
            return

    def _read_data(self):
        self.ids = [1,2,3,10]
        self.sock_common.execute(self.params['dbname'], self.uid, self.params['password'], 'res.partner', 'read', self.ids, ['name'])
```

This is the main code:

```
for row in reader:
    print idx, xml_port, row

    if idx == 0:
        header = row

    else:
        # Create new User threads
        thread_ = theUser(idx, row, dbhost, xml_port, dbuser, dbpassword, dbname)

        # Start new User Threads
        thread_.start()

        # Add threads to thread list    
        threads.append(thread_)

    idx += 1
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `xml_port` when you create `theUser`, it should be:

```
thread_ = theUser(idx, row, dbhost, xml_port, dbuser, dbpassword, dbname)
```

And `self.sock_common` won't be set if an exception is raised.You can move it to `run()` function.

To read `res.partner`:

```
def _read_data(self):
    self.ids = [1,2,3,10]
    models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://%s:%s/xmlrpc/object' % (dbhost, xml_port))
    res = models.execute(self.params['dbname'], self.uid, self.params['password'], 'res.partner', 'read', self.ids, ['name'])
    print res
```

You can check if a given user is permited to read using:

```
models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
'res.partner', 'check_access_rights',
['read'], {'raise_exception': False})
```

If the user can read, it should return `true`.

> This script is from [Odoo Web Service API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html)

Comment: Very Thanks  Kenly, now i can login with concurrent connection..

i've update my code, and now i tried to read via xml_rpc with multithread.
Open Connection/Login is OK, but the i always get the fail return on reading method..

can u help me too pls..

Comment: @green43 To read `res.partner` we need to use `xmlrpc/object`.Check my edit.

Comment: Thx @Kenly, i tried it.. Now i got this result:
1. some thread success login + reading, 
2. some thread success login, but failed on reading (I Print the error msg and it said **<10061, 'Connection refused'>**)
3. and some thread failed at login (I Print the error msg and it said **<10061, 'Connection refused'>**,  same as the reading error message)

Comment: Thank you so much, its running well.. :)
The problem is why some thread giving the error message **Connection refused**? Fyi, this thread/user is not unique, e.g: 1st testing result is user1 error Connection Refused, and 2nd testing result is user2 error Connection Refused.
Have you any idea about it? im stuck in there now..